# Masstransit with azure service bus: Why Messages go to the queue_skipped?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I am using Masstransit with Azure service .net5.

I have two applications:

Web Api. Startup:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
   x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context,cfg) =>
   {
      cfg.Host("Endpoint");

      cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("mytopic", e =>
         {
             e.PrefetchCount = 100;
             e.MaxConcurrentCalls = 100;
         });
      cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

Web Api. Event Publish Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<bool> Get()
{
    await _bus.Publish(new Message()
    {
        Name = "Test Name",
        Description = "Test Description",
        Order = 1
    });

    return true;
}
```

Worker service. Program:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<MessageConsumer>();
    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context,cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host("Endpoint");
        cfg.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("mytopic", e =>
        {
            e.PrefetchCount = 100;
            e.MaxConcurrentCalls = 100;
            e.ConfigureConsumer<MessageConsumer>(context);
        });
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
services.AddMassTransitHostedService(true);
```

Worker service. Consumer:

```
public class MessageConsumer : IConsumer<Message>
    {
        readonly ILogger<MessageConsumer> _logger;

        public MessageConsumer(ILogger<MessageConsumer> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Message> context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Received Text: {Text}", context.Message.Name);
        }
    }
```

Both applications have event class (Message class in code) which are in the same namespace.

```
namespace EventBusMessages
{
    public class Message
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public string Description { get; set; }
        
        public int Order { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After successfully sending and processing a message, the next message is placed in the queue ***_skipped. Then next message is again processed successfully but then again ***_skipped.

Example of a Publish console:

```
[05:26:19 DBG] SEND sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/EventBusMessages/Message c7710000-e64a-00ff-df61-08d92e12a05d EventBusMessages.
Message
[05:26:20 DBG] SEND sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/EventBusMessages/Message c7710000-e64a-00ff-216c-08d92e12a182 EventBusMessages.
Message
[05:26:20 DBG] SKIP sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/mytopic c7710000-e64a-00ff-216c-08d92e12a182
[05:26:21 INF] MOVE sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/mytopic c7710000-e64a-00ff-216c-08d92e12a182 mytopic_skipped dead-letter
[05:26:22 DBG] SEND sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/EventBusMessages/Message c7710000-e64a-00ff-fc4d-08d92e12a27a EventBusMessages.
Message
[05:26:23 DBG] SEND sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/EventBusMessages/Message c7710000-e64a-00ff-d1a8-08d92e12a30b EventBusMessages.
Message
[05:26:23 DBG] SKIP sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/mytopic c7710000-e64a-00ff-d1a8-08d92e12a30b
[05:26:23 INF] MOVE sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/mytopic c7710000-e64a-00ff-d1a8-08d92e12a30b mytopic_skipped dead-letter
```

05:26:19 and 05:26:22 were successfully processed by the consumer, but 05:26:20 and 05:26:23
have been skipped and moved to the ***_skipped queue

Example a Consumer console:

```
[05:26:19 DBG] RECEIVE sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/mytopic c7710000-e64a-00ff-df61-08d92e12a05d EventBusMessages.Message EventB
usSubscriber.MessageConsumer(00:00:00.0126036)
[05:26:22 INF] Received Text: Test Name
[05:26:22 DBG] RECEIVE sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/mytopic c7710000-e64a-00ff-fc4d-08d92e12a27a EventBusMessages.Message EventB
usSubscriber.MessageConsumer(00:00:00.0042202)
```

Again, I send the same message every time

do thanks for answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Web API project should not have a receive endpoint – it has no consumers configured. So every message will be skipped by that receive endpoint. You only configure receive endpoints when you have consumers.

And you only need to call `ConfigureEndpoints` when you've added consumers.

Comment: Indeed. Removing ReceiveEndpoint and ConfigureEndpoints from the Web Api helped. Thank you very much!